# how to search datagridview with multiple conditions?

Tags: vb.net

i am developing a simple library management system. i filter my datagridview1 using two combo boxes with two criterias.
when i enter first condition filtering is doing well.But after addinng 2nd and 3rd condition, only one conditon is working and others do not do filtering.how to solve this problem? thanks

```
   Private Sub combobox4_TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox4.TextChange


    If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withButton1.Checked Then
        BooksBindingSource.Filter = "[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'"

        BooksBindingSource.Filter = "[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [catagory] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'"
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Patrick, you are correct, i concentrate two separete if statements together. But it never filtering...

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd assignment overrides the Filter. You need to combine your conditions to make them work simultaneously like:

```
Dim dateFilter As String = "[Added_Date] LIKE " & combobox2.Text & "%'"

Dim publisherFilter As String = "[Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'"
Dim categoryFilter As String = "[catagory] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'"
' TODO: customize the 3rd filter
Dim someOtherFilter As String = "[...] LIKE '" & combobox123.Text & "%'"

BooksBindingSource.Filter = publisherFilter & " OR " & categoryFilter & " OR " & someOtherFilter

' do we have a date filter?
If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withButton1.Checked Then
    ' add the date filter
    BooksBindingSource.Filter = dateFilter & " AND (" & BooksBindingSource.Filter & ")"
End If
```

Comment: dear, please explain an example with full code. Because i am newbie.thanks

Comment: BooksBindingSource.Filter = BooksBindingSource.Filter & "[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'"       useless....

Comment: @aksl that example may be missing an `OR` or `AND` between the two conditions.

Comment: Yes, correct. Just add "AND" in front. I'll update the code. Wait for it.

Comment: Dear  battlmonstr, Just added your updated code to form. But unfortunately it does not filtering..

Comment: Try to debug to see how the final Filter condition looks like. Post your data definition. I assumed that each of the filters works separately as you described.

Comment: Dear battlmonstr, tested,each of the filters works separately well. But they doesn't work together....

Comment: Do you have any error message? How the data looks like? What do you expect to see before and after filtering?

Comment: `filters.Add("[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%' OR [catagory] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'")` If the only difference is the `catagory` and or `Publisher`, you need an `OR` condition...

Comment: dear  battlmonstr, not give error massage. but filter result is empty. i mean no rows show

Comment: Dear  Çöđěxěŕ, your code works very well. how to combine it to 3rd filter. i modified as this                     filters.Add("[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%' OR [catagory] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'") Or [Author] Like '" & combobox4.Text & "%'")
             but never filter

Comment: Updated the code with explanation comments, changed AND to OR, added template for the 3rd condition. Please take your time to understand it before dismissing.

Comment: Simplified the code to match the task (as I understand it).

Comment: according to codexer, i modified the multisearch code as follows                    
'Dim filters As New List(Of String)        If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withButton1.Checked Then
            filters.Add("[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%' OR [catagory] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%' OR [Author] LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'")
        End If         BooksBindingSource.Filter = String.Join(" AND ", filters)
End Sub'  filter works  but gives wrong results.Ex:Author"Herath" with Added Date "1999" but shows also 2000 records.

Comment: Help me with this problem. filter works. results are the correct ones with incorrect records. cant believe. but it is!

Comment: Do you understand what AND and OR mean? Please take your time to understand the code. Ask questions if you don't understand something.